# weblogic jndi lookup anonymous user

Tags: security, weblogic, jndi

Using welogic 10. I am passing the java.naming.security.principal and  java.naming.security.credentials explicitly to the InitialContext and I can see the values when by making initialContext.getEnvironment(). However when I call lookup on this intialContext object, I get the below message:

User  does not have permission on  to perform lookup operation.

My question is that, even though I am passing the security credentials explicitly in the intialContext, why is weblogic still saying user is 'anonymous'?

The values in getEnvironment of IntialContext, just before calling the lookup method:

ic.getEnvironment():: {java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=weblogic.jndi.factories:weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.url:weblogic.jndi.factories:weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.url, java.naming.security.principal=username, java.naming.security.credentials=password}

Comment: And the user/pass you're using is a member of the admin group? Have a look here: http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/06/14/securing-the-jndi-with-admin-role-in-11g/ https://forums.oracle.com/message/6498996

Comment: the user/pass is part of the roles allowed to do the lookup. Similar to what is there in the first link in your post.